# Can I integrate laravel app with static website written by Gatsby.js and React?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dns, gatsby

I built an app by laravel and Vue.js. 
I have an idea to add a blog section to my app.
For me, I have two ideas now.

1.To put a WordPress website into laravel public folder. Then, I will be able to run a blog website in laravel app's subdirectory.(Using the same domain is essential for SEO.)

2.Create a headless CMS using React and Gatsby.js. For admin function, I will build a graqhql server by wordpress, and retrieve data from it to show contents on a Gatsby.js blog website.

What I want to ask is regarding my second question.

> Can I integrate Gatsby.js and laravel? Because I want to use the same
>   domain. I am using AWS ec2 apache server.